# What is the simplest way to find a development job in Canada for a non-Canadian?

Tags: software-industry, international

I am thinking about moving to Canada. As I understand right now it is required to have a job offer in order to do so. Can anyone recommend a way to do so ?

Comment: Hi MichaelT, and welcome to The Workplace! Could you please clarify if your question is about where to look for employment in Canada, or the legal issues around being a non-Canadian working in Canada? Thanks!

Comment: Basically I asking how a non Canadian can find a job offer from a Canadian company.

Comment: Besides applying for one?

Comment: I don't really see what about this situation requires specific expertise...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly, it's the same as applying for a job anywhere: find someone you know who can refer you, or find job listings and apply.

I don't really know the immigration rules, so I can't speak to that. I suggest going to http://www.cic.gc.ca/ and familiarizing yourself with the rules. It does look like there's a quota of 10,000 people who can immigrate per year without a job offer, and that it's used up for this year.

Do you have a city in mind you'd like to move to? Any of the big cities (Vancouver, Toronto, or Montreal) have a significant tech industry, as do Waterloo and Ottawa, and maybe a few others. Any of these places should have plenty of employers looking for people.

Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Are Canadian companies willing to consider someone who is not willing in Canada as potential employee ? Are some companies are more willing to do so compared to other, how could I find such companies, are some recruitment agencies exist that specialize in such type of job finding ?

Comment: In my (limited) experience, yes they are but I can't point to any particular companies or agencies to look at. There's no discrimination against foreigners that I've seen, just the deterrent of having to deal with immigration issues. There's rules, like having to first try to hire local workers before offering the job to foreign workers, which are a pain to deal with and ties up their HR staff.